# For which values of $p$ and $q$ is the integral convergent and absolutely convergent : $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x^p\,dx}{1+x^q}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> For which values of $p$ and $q$ is the integral convergent and absolutely convergent :
> $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x^p\,dx}{1+x^q}$$

**My try :**

Let $$f(x) = \frac{x^p}{1+x^q}$$

For $q \gt 0$ :

Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^{q-p}}$ on $[1, \infty]$.
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} 
= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^q}{1+x^q} 
= 1 \ne 0.
$$

Thus $\int g$ and $\int f$ converge together.

Now, $\int g$ converges iff $q-p \gt 1$ i.e. $q \gt 1+p$, so does $\int f$.

I'm not sure that if this concludes the case $q \gt 0$.

Also what can I do when $q \le 0$.

I neee some help please.

Also since the integrand is positive in the given interval so I guess whenever it's convergent, it is absolutely convergent. So I don't need to work it out separately. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are correct about absolute convergence: the function being integrated is positive in this interval so convergence and absolute convergence are the same thing here.
2. Your calculation for $q>0$ is correct.
3. For $q<0$ the denominator of the integrand tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to infinity, which means that the integrand $\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}$ behaves roughly like $x^p$, and since $\int_1^{\infty} x^p dx$ converges if and only if $p<-1$ then the same is true for the original integral. Of course to prove this rigorously we use the comparison test: for $q<0$ we have
   $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{x^p}{1+x^q}}{x^p}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^q}=1$$
   so that for $q<0$ the integral converges if and only if $p<-1$.
4. For $q=0$ we get in a similar way that the integrand behaves like $x^p$ and we prove it in the same way using the comparison test.

Comment: Thanks. So let me summarise, the integral is convergent when $(i)$ $q\gt 0$ and $q\gt p+1$ and $(ii)$ $q\le 0$ and $p\lt -1$. Am I right? Can't we combine these and make some compact inequality relationship between $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @Itachi Yes, you are correct. You can't write this using a single inequality. If we plot the regions $x>0\land x>y+1$ and $x\leq 0\land y<-1$ in the $x,y$ plane then we see there is no reason to expect that there is a simple inequality that describes both of these parts together.

Comment: @Itachi (Of course it would be possible to use some trick with indicator functions to write this without splitting into two parts, but that would not be desirable as it would only complicate the solution.)

Comment: Thanks again mate :)